Documentation on dbt tests not generated at dbt docs
I am trying to provide documentation for a dbt tests.
I have created a test validating the sum of 2 numbers (of course, this is just an example).
{% test test_sum(summand_a, summand_b, total) %}
SELECT 
    {{summand_a}} + {{summand_b}} AS result 
WHERE result <> {{total}}
{% endtest %}

I have created a test.yml file next to the test with the following content:
version: 2

tests:
  - name: test_sum
    description: 'This test validates the sum of 2 numbers'

When generating dbt docs via dbt docs generate the test does not show any documentation.
I expect the test do be documented when serving the docs via dbt docs serve

Currently, I believe you cannot document custom generic tests directly inside the /tests/generic folder.
A workaround is to:

Have your generic test (called test_sum) stored under /tests/generic
update the macros.yml in the /macros directory (note the name has to have the prefix test_, so not sure if you need test_test_sum below, or just test_sum will work):

name: test_sum
description: <your test description>
arguments:
  - name: summand_a
    type: number
    description: <desc>
  - name: summand_b
    type: number
    description: <desc>
  - name: result
    type: number
    description: <desc>



With this the documentation should then show:

Description
<your test description>


Thanks for the responde @aleix! I will give it a try sooner or later! I will keep you posted
